# Django overrides a Button in Crispy Form

Tags: django, forms

I've got a first form as following:

```
class SupplierRegistrationSupplementForm(forms.ModelForm):
    siret = FRSIRETField()

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SupplierRegistrationSupplementForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_class = 'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.form_id = 'company_supplement_form'
        self.helper.form_action = "."
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.add_input(
            Submit('submit', _('Save'),
                   css_class="btn-primary btn-lg",
                   css_id="save_company"
                   )
        )
```

I need to inherit from it but with a different button. In order to change the button id, I would have done this:

```
class SupplierUpdateForm(SupplierRegistrationSupplementForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         self.helper.form_tag = False
    self.helper.add_input(
        Submit('submit', _('Save'),
               css_class="btn-primary btn-lg",
               css_id="save_user"
               )
    )
```

But it adds a new button to the previous one. Is it possible to remove the first one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `add_inputs`, [the code](https://github.com/maraujop/django-crispy-forms/blob/dev/crispy_forms/helper.py#L279) appends the input to `self.inputs`. So a quick hack would be to pop the existing input from the list before adding the new one.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
     super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
     ...
     self.inputs.pop()
     self.helper.add_input(...)
```

However this is fragile, because it assumes that there is exactly one input. It might be better to have a `BaseSupplierForm` which does not have any inputs, then have two subclasses `SupplierRegistrationSupplementForm` and `SupplierUpdateForm`, which both define their own inputs.